# Opencart admin page 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: json, compiler-errors, opencart, admin, opencart2.x

I have opencart Version 2.0.1.1 and recently i have noticed a strange error. when i visit the sale/order page it is showing a popup with the error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
 <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
 </head><body>
 <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
 <p>The document has moved <a href="https://webdomain.com/?route=api/voucher/add&amp;api=api%2Fvoucher%2Fadd">here</a>.</p>
 </body></html>
```

what is this error and how we can resolve this ? any idea? i am totally blank on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in **Admin** panel:

- Go to *System > Users > API*.
- Add a new API, generate password, and **enable** it, add your IP address in **IP** tab.
- Then go to *Admin > System > Settings > Edit*, tab *Option*.
- Select API user under Checkout section as your API user.
- Save the changes.
- Go to *Sales > Orders* to check if error is gone.

Comment: I have checked there are already two apis there, so i think it is fine, but i cant find the other "checkout section in settings" https://prnt.sc/tf4oen

Comment: ok i have found it. As API and user were already set , so to be confirm i have created a new API user and set it, and still error is there.

Comment: When this error started from? Maybe there was something? New modules installed? New hosting?

Comment: nothing have been changed on the website it is start showing error since 3 or 4 weeks, within that cancel order is not working as wel